# How am I able to output items of different list together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, for-loop

My code is giving me a browse-folder window where I'm choosing a top folder dir, this is then stored in a variable.
From there I'm looking for specifically named folders. Which are stored in a list.
After finding these I want to find their sizes and paths.

So I want to store and easy access, multiple items in different lists. I tried to write the code without classes as I don't know how to make it work.
I'm thankful for all suggestions and solutions to make the code better. I think I have to probably restructure the whole code.

**Currently, it looks like this:**

```
Folder = Folder1_Name, Folder2_Name, Folder3_Name
Path = Folder1_Path, Folder2_Path, Folder3_Path
Size = Folder1_Size, Folder2_Size, Folder3_Size
```

**That is what I want:**

```
Proj1 = Folder1_Name, Folder1_Size, Folder1_Path
Proj2 = Folder2_Name, Folder2_Size, Folder2_Path
Proj3 = Folder3_Name, Folder3_Size, Folder3_Path
```

My current Code

```
import os
import re

# Choose Folderpath
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
userpromp_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
os.chdir(userpromp_path)

#potencialprojects = ['1901_Default_Project2', '1910_Default_Project']


# Define String Match for Project
p = ''.join(["^", # Start of string being matched
             "[0-2]", # First character a number 0 through 2 (less than 3)
             "[6-9]", # Second character a number 6 through 9 (single digit greater than 5)
             "(0(?=[0-9])|1(?=[0-2]))", # (lookahead) A 0 followed only by any number 0 through 9 **OR** A 1 followed only by any number 0 through 2
             "((?<=0)[1-9]|(?<=1)[0-2])", # (lookbehind) Match 1-9 if the preceding character was a 0, match 0-2 if the preceding was a 1
             "_", # Next char is a "_"
             "[A-Z]", #Next char (only) is an upper A through Z
              ".*$" # Match anything until end of string
    ])

projectnames_found = []
projectpathes_found = []
projectsizes_found = []

def find_projects(searchpath):
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(searchpath):
        for projectname in subdirs:
            if re.match(p, projectname):

                projectnames_found.append(projectname)
                projectpathes_found.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),projectname))


def get_size(scan_paths = '.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(scan_paths):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            if not os.path.islink(fp):
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)

    return round((((total_size/1000)/1000)/1000), 2), 'GB'


find_projects(userpromp_path)

for projectpath_found in projectpathes_found:
    projectsizes_found.append(get_size(projectpath_found))



for a in projectnames_found, projectpathes_found, projectsizes_found:
    print(a, '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `zip()` function ([Link to documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip))

Your code should look something like this:

```
zipped = zip(Folder, Path, Size)
projects = list(zipped)
```

Now, `projects` is a list where each index refers to a tuple containing each project's information. For example:

```
projects[0] # This contains the first project information
projects[0][0] # This is Folder1_Name
projects[0][1] # This is Folder1_Path
projects[1][2] # This is Folder2_Size
```